# scanning a line of strings with spaces using scanf

Tags: c, input, scanf, stdio

I was using scanf for all my inputs in C. Now I saw other similar questions about `scanf()` and they suggested using `fgets()` instead of `scanf()`. I will do so in the future. However, at the moment this particular part of code with `scanf()` never seems to work. I know there is a solution.

My code is:

```
#define LENGTH 1000
#define WORD 100
int main(){
    int i = 0;
    char s[WORD][LENGTH];
    do {
        scanf("%s", s[i]);
        i++;
    }
    while (s[i][strlen(s[i])] != EOF);
    printf("%s\n", s);

    return 0;
}
```

There should be something instead of `EOF` in the while loop which checks for the end of line. The final result should be an array of words in `s[]` and the program should print that array of words without spaces.

Comment: I came across `while (scanf("%s", &str[strlen(str)]) == 1)`. I am totally new here. As Iharob Al Asimi explained it is wrong. Can you, please, explain why this solution is not correct? or why I can't use it in my code?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `scanf()` does not read the character you need to check for end of line, or at least not using `"%s"` as the specifier.

Instead, use the following

```
char line[100];
if (scanf("%99[^\n]", line) == 1) {
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", line);
}
```

This way, it does not stop at white space characters, and it behaves similar to `fgets()`, except that it does not read the `'\n'` character and that might be a problem if you call it again.

Comment: now I understand scanf() has very limited use. Is there any way that my code  can exit from the while loop with string arrays stored in the memory? so that I am able to use the array s[] later in the program.

Comment: You can use the same trick used for strings, note that your question doesn't appear to ask for that. The simple solution is, COUNT THE WORDS and keep a variable with that value so you can use it in later. The complicated solution is, use pointers and add a `NULL` pointer at the end of your words array, then `for (int i = 0 ; s[i] != NULL ; ++i) ...` would iterate through all the words, the same thing done for strings.

Comment: Well, I found one working solution for scanf(): `while (scanf("%s", &s[strlen(s)]) == 1);` This will ensure that a full line is scanned until 'enter'

Comment: @SaidAkbar This looks bad, isn't your compiler throwing a bunch of warnings like crazy? Don't use `strlen()` like that, read the manual.

Comment: Surprisingly, that code is working correctly on gcc and it passed all tests correctly. Apparently, scanf() can also handle a line of strings with spaces.

Comment: I was using this `fgets(str,LENGTH,stdin)` to get a line of strings. Now this code does the same job: `while (scanf("%s", &str[strlen(str)]) == 1)`.

Comment: This CODE IS WRONG, please don't do that.

Comment: `while (scanf("%s", &str[strlen(str)]) == 1)` is completely wrong. Use what was suggested `while (scanf("%99[^\n]", str) == 1)`.